# The data source does not support server-side data paging. gridview

Tags: asp.net

There are 2 button.In click on button1,showing data in gridview and second button,exporting into excel.I has created gridview and allow paging.In export(button2) function,making paging to false for taking all data in one excel.At the end of export function making paging to true.When I will click on button1,it does not show previous data.I want like that.

```
Button1_click()
{
 Gridview1.Datasource ="";
 Gridview.DataBind();
 function1();
}


Button2_click()
{
function1()
  Gridview1.AllowPaging = false; 

//code for export grid
//End
Gridview1.AllowPaging = false; 
Gridview.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In `Button1_Click` you are setting the `DataSource` to "", you are clearing the data when you do that.  You have to re-assign your `DataSource` or don't clear it.

Comment: Hi rick schott ,for ur help.Suppose there is no record,then it should not show previous record.I have to make Gridview1.Datasource ="";.

Comment: If Gridview1.Datasource ="", then you will get nothing returned.  Don't call DataBind() if you want the data from ViewState.

Comment: if there is entry for id:2 in database,then it shows in grid.If there is no id:7 in dtabase,it should not show result for id:2,which is previously click

Comment: In function1(),I am writing select query.Taking data in ds and assigning to gridview.if there is entry for id:2 in database,then it shows in grid.If there is no id:7 in dtabase,it should not show result for id:2,which is previously click.That's why I was trying to make grid null at the starting button.

Answer (score 0):

you should use DataTable to fill Gridview.